# Convert mm to cm with jQuery | Gravity Form

Tags: jquery, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

Why doesn't the below work, and how should I do this?

Do you have a better and shorter way to write this code?

".Select_unit" is the class name of Radiobutton (I learned from User Rochelle :) Thank You!)

---

My Gravity Form:
[image]

---

```
$(function() {

var W_val;
var H_val;

      //set width textbox Value to W_val
    $('#input_2_1').keyup(function() {
      W_val = $("#input_2_1").val();
    });

      //set Height textbox Value to H_val
    $('#input_2_2').keyup(function() {
      H_val = $("#input_2_2").val();
    });


     //Change Unit mm to cm
$('.Select_Unit input[type="radio"]').on('change',function(){
     
    var radioValue = $('input[name="#input_2_3"]:checked').val();

    if (radioValue=="cm")
        {
            $("#input_2_1").val(W_val);
            $("#input_2_2").val(H_val);
        }
    else
        {
            $("#input_2_1").val((W_val*10));
            $("#input_2_2").val((H_val*10));
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: Can you add the required HTML so we can run it in a snippet?

Comment: See: https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ *it's not working* - are there any console errors? do you have jquery included? Do any of your events actually fire?  Or is the selector incorrect?

Comment: @freedomn-m 
just unit selector is incorrect, other events are fire...

Comment: Without any HTML, not much we can do to help you.  If we provide the HTML to generate a working solution, it won't be the same as yours.  See [mcve].

Comment: Just spotted this `input[name="#input_2_3"]` - do you have an `<input id="#input_2_3">` seems unlikely - try with `input[name="input_2_3"]`.  What's the value of `radioValue` when you debug it?

Comment: I'm using Gravity Form builder, without HTML,

Comment: Code appears to work "fine" (ie not sure what it's supposed to do, but it does something) with `name=input_2_3` https://jsfiddle.net/gpfo1eqb/ so looks like a typo

Comment: *I'm using Gravity Form builder, without HTML* - what does the "form builder" actually *build*?  Yep, HTML.   Open page in browser, view source / inspect element.

Comment: @freedomn-m here is the Html code: https://jpst.it/2DqNN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your html, there is a `div`

```
<div class='gfield_radio' id='input_2_3'>
```

as this is a `div`, it's not an `input` so the selector `$('input[name="input_2_3"]')` returns no inputs, so `.val()` is *always* undefined.

```
var radioValue = $('input[name="input_2_3"]:checked').val();
```

the radioValue selector needs to be:

```
var radioValue = $('#input_2_3 input:checked').val();
```

Then it works: https://jsfiddle.net/57rx2guo/

Answer (score 0):

Thank You!

```
var radioValue = $('input[name="input_3"]:checked').val();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).